# Removing NA from Date class variable

Tags: r, data.table

Could anyone explain me what's happening and also how can I remove this NA value from this data frame without changing the class of the Date NA variable?

```
> a = data.frame(k = as.Date(NA))
> 
> for (j in names(a)) {
+   set(a, which(is.na(a[[j]])), j, 0)
+ }
> 
> a
           k
1 1970-01-01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since column `k` is of class `Date` and when you `set` it to 0, it changes the column value to

```
as.Date(0) #which is
#[1] "1970-01-01"
```

To remove `NA` values `na.omit(a)` would be enough I guess?

Comment: I mean, I don't want to lose the entire row, just replace NA by zero.

Comment: 0 is not a valid date object. It is only a number. You need to change the class of the column if you want to place 0.